# What is recommended way to determine if a Redux state empty array is the initial state or the result of an API call that returns an empty array?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let say I have an initial state tree that looks like this:

```
    {
      users: [],
      items: []
    }
```

In some cases, the result of calling the items API endpoint may result in a state tree like this:

```
    {
      users: [],
      items: [
              {itemId: 100, itemName: "Something100"},
              {itemId: 101, itemName: "Something101"}
             ]
    }
```

In other cases where there are not items to display, the state tree *after* an API call will be identical to the initial state tree.

Now in my component I'm using useEffect, something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      if (items.length === 0) {
        actions.loadItems().catch((error) => {
          alert("Loading items failed! " + error);
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
  }, [items , actions]);
```

In this particular case, the length of items will be 0 in two cases: initial state or in case there are no results. If the API returns zero items and items.length === 0, then the action to call the API is executed repeatedly.

We really need a way of knowing that the empty array is the initial state or not. Of course I could change the state tree to something like:

```
    {
      users: {isLoaded: false, records: []},
      items: {isLoaded: false, records: []},
    }
```

That is going to add a bunch of overhead and refactoring and may not be most efficient/effective, so can someone give me a recommendation?

Comment: Why do you need to repeatedly make API calls if it returns 0 items?

Comment: If you want to differentiate the two cases, can't you initially set them to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need some way of tracking the initialisation. If the issue is having to refactor then you can pull out this initialisation state into a higher order in the object from what you suggested. This will avoid refactoring so much:

```
{
  isUsersLoaded: false,
  isItemsLoaded: false,
  users: [],
  items: []
}
```

Another alternative is to init like this and check if `users !== null` etc.:

```
{
  users: null,
  items: null
}
```

Comment: I went with setting the initial state to null. For some reason I assumed you couldn't do that.

The useEffect just checks for `!items` to fire off API call